# nopCommerce plugin backward compatibility?

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce

I have found the plugin for the payment method I need which has two available versions: One that works with 3.4 and one that works with 3.7. I am using version 3.5 and can't upgrade the version at this point in time (I won't go into that now).

When I add either of the plugins, neither of them show in the list of local plugins in order to install them (I have checked that the location is correct - \Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins) even after clicking the 'Reload list of plugins' button.

If I add 3.50 to the list of 'SupportedVersions' in Description.txt it breaks the project completely.

Which version should I be using, and if the 3.7 version how can I make it work with 3.5?

I also tried the version that has 3.00 as the 'SupportedVersions' - I've tried everything I can think of.

I do not have the source projects for the plugins, they are produced by a third party.

Thanks

Comment: I've also written to them asking but not had a reply yet, but need an answer fairly quickly.

Comment: Write the name of the plugin.

Comment: @Dmitry it's Payments.BarclaysEpdq-v3 or Payments.BarclaysEpdq-v4

Comment: you downloaded it from our shop? search shows that we do not have such a plug-in

Comment: @Dmitry no, it is provided for free here https://www.vooservers.com/technical-blog/barclays-epdq-nopcommerce-module/

Comment: you should contact the developer and ask him to explain why he does not work with plugin version 3.5. Maybe he will take to make a version for the old nopCommerce, or you can also try upgrade to version 3.7